# PhantomJS Get Document Elements Positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to get positions of certain elements on the page, for instance iframes or objects. Presently I

```
page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        // Select attr etc.. 
        position = $(this).position();
        offset = $(this).offset();
    });
});
```

I've tried adding $(window).load() to the formula but it still isn't returning the correct element position a lot of the time. Especially with iFrames and Objects. Perhaps they're positioned after the DOM has loaded? Either way does anyone have any ideas how I can improve or change method to get much more accurate positions?

Kind regards,

Fab

Comment: I've also tried using timeouts

Answer (score 3):

What position is being returned? How is it incorrect?

A few things.

1) When `page.evaluate` is invoked the page has already loaded. That happens at `page.open` time. `window.onload` will never fire inside `page.evaluate`; it has already fired.

2) I don't know what `this` is within `page.evaluate`.

3) Within a PhantomJS context, there's no real reason to use jQuery. You're better off using standard constructs such as `document.documentElement.scrollTop`.

Try this:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
    console.log(document.getElementById("my-frame").getBoundingClientRect());
});
```

Comment: @torazuburo Thanks for the advice. I have changed the code but the position return is still a little off.

2) The reference to $(this) was just my avoiding adding the selector jQuery.

`URL: http://mp3lemon.org/artist/16397/`

    `page.evaluate(function() {`
    `console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);`
    `var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');`
    `for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {`
        `console.log(JSON.stringify(iframes[i].getBoundingClientRect())); }`
    `});`

The left is fine. Top is a few pixels too much. So when cropping it will not be right.

Comment: It's not consistently off too. Sometimes it is perfect. Sometimes the left hand side position is off. 

Basically my getBoundingClientRect() or position() or offset() are not 100% true. So if cropping/highlighting these regions it doesn't look right.

Comment: @Fabien, I use this consistently and also occasionally encounter problems, usually with the left side, and sometimes ranging in the neighborhood of 50-100 pixels (too small). It has worked for me ensure that the page size is not causing funny clipping or folding artifacts, by doing something like `page.viewportSize={width: 2048, height: 16000};`.

Comment: @torazuburo Thank you for the reply. The pages I go through often very in size quite dramatically. If I set the viewport that large will the files be much larger than I need? (I do save the images after)